# How can I parallelize simple operations across multiple devices?

Tags: parallel-processing, partitioning, distributed, offloading

I've written some simple code using Android Studio tool. The code I've written enables four simple operations as follows:

- Add two numbers
- Subtract one number from another
- Multiply two numbers
- Divide two numbers

I want to parallelize and run each of these operations on different mobile devices. Let's say I have 4 mobile devices connected through wireless to the same network that my PC is connected. So, I want to offload Addition to run on mobile device A, Subtraction to run on mobile device B, Multiplication to run on mobile device C and Division to run on mobile device D.

How can I accomplish this task? I have read about multiple threading, asynchronous tasks, and nearby API but with no luck to discover how exactly to achieve that since my knowledge about Android Studio is limited.

I am wondering if anyone came across such thing? or any advise that can guide me in the right direction.

Comment: edited: separate into paragraphs, make intent clearer.

Comment: I really need help with this, as it is a requirement for my project, any help with this guys? please let me know if my question needs more details, or not clear??